# Snowball change in radius

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, phase-transition, differentiation, estimation

So in this question I do not understand what derivative to use and how to relate it to the problem.

A spherical snowball with an outer layer of ice melts so that the volume of the snowball decreases at a rate of 2.0 cm3/min How fast is the radius changing when diameter of the snowball is 0.10 m?

I understand that because we are talking about the rate of change of something we will use a derivative. The problem also poses the question how fast is the radius changing. So we want to know the derivative r in respect to time. Not sure where to go from there. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try expressing the volume of the snowball as a function of the radius, keeping in mind it's a sphere, and applying the chain rule to find an expression for $\frac{dR}{dt}$. Hint: $\frac{dV}{dt}=-(2)(10^{-6})(\frac{1}{60})$, using volume of a sphere as V, and finding $\frac{dV}{dR}$.

Comment: So why would I want to express the volume as a function of the radius? I know the answer at the end but I am trying to dig deep and understand each step. Thanks in advance

Comment: So you would want to find the expression for $\frac{dR}{dt}$, given $\frac{dV}{dt}$. To do this,  you want to find a relation between V and R in order to be able to find an expression for $\frac{dV}{dt}$. Does this help your understanding of the method?

Comment: Oh Ok that helps me understand better. So Volume =4/3 pi r^3. The derivative of that gives us dv/dt which is 4pi r^2. Now we would want to find a relationship between 4pi r^2 and dr/dt.

Comment: I guess my next question is how do I relate dr/dt to dv/dt?

Comment: My teacher multiplied 4pi r^2  by dr/dt . This is what I am unsure of ....@eigen

Comment: To relate $\frac{dR}{dt}$ to $\frac{dV}{dt}$, you could do it by $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dR} \frac{dR}{dt}$. This is the chain rule, and since $\frac{d}{dR}(\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3)$=$(4\pi r^2)$ you can see this is what your teacher was doing.

Comment: Ok thank you so much ! I got it now ! Thank you I understand it now.